# Fast Fourier Transform in Objective-C doesn't work fine

Tags: objective-c, signal-processing, fft, accelerate-framework

I have a method in `Objective-C` that receives an `array of doubles` and then it uses the `Fast Fourier Transform`, however the exit of the `FFT` doesn't match to what I want.

Can someone help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

This is my method where `fftLength` is 4096:

```
-(double(*)) doFFT:(double(*))data{
    double (*fft) = malloc((fftLength * 2) * sizeof(double));

    FFTSetupD fft_weights = vDSP_create_fftsetupD((log2((double)(fftLength))), kFFTRadix2);

    DSPDoubleSplitComplex fftData;
    //fftData.imagp = fftMagnitudes;

    fftData.imagp = (double*)malloc(fftLength * sizeof(double));
    fftData.realp = (double*)malloc(fftLength * sizeof(double));

    for (int i=0; i< fftLength; i++) {
        fftData.realp[i] = (double)data[i];
        fftData.imagp[i] = (double)0.0;

    }

    vDSP_fft_zipD(fft_weights, &fftData, 1, log2((double)(fftLength)), FFT_FORWARD);

    for(int i = 0;i<fftLength * 2;i++){
        fft[i] = fftData.realp[i];
        fft[i+1] = fftData.imagp[i];
    }

    return fft;
}
```

And this is part of my input data:

```
[0.0,2.092731423889438E-4, 8.858534436404497E-4,0.0013714427743574675,0.0012678166431137061,-9.650789019044481E-4,-0.002852548808273958,-0.005176802258252122,-0.007281581949909022,-0.00575977878132905,…]
```

And the result should be:

```
[21478.183372382526,0.0,-10190.412374839314,…]
```

But I'm not getting this.

Comment: Assume that log2 has rounding errors, and log2 (1024) might be 9.99999999999999 which gets round down to 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is wrong:

```
for(int i = 0;i<fftLength * 2;i++){
    fft[i] = fftData.realp[i];
    fft[i+1] = fftData.imagp[i];
}
```

Assuming you want interleaved real/complex output data then it should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fftLength; i++) {
    fft[i * 2] = fftData.realp[i];
    fft[i * 2 + 1] = fftData.imagp[i];
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for the answer, but the problem is the ffData.realp[i] is wrong, for example the ffData.realp[0] should be 21478.183372382526, and the value that i'm getting is not that after doing this vDSP_fft_zipD(fft_weights, &fftData, 1, log2((double)(fftLength)), FFT_FORWARD);.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to interleave the data. In which case it's the incremental in the loop ought be (i+=2) ?

Comment: @Jef: well the intention is not totally clear, but the fixed version of the loop I've given above will interleave the real/complex values, whereas the original version didn't do anything useful.

Comment: @Sergio: what value do you get and what are you using as your reference for the expected value ?

Comment: @PaulR i'm getting this in fftData.realp[0] 441.09802769895668. The reference is in Android, they got 21478.183372382526, and it's the real value. I don't know what is wrong in mi data.

Comment: Do any of the other values match, e.g. `fftData.realp[1]`,  `fftData.realp[2]` ?

Comment: @PaulR No, the other values doesn't match.

Comment: @Sergio: one other question: what FFT library are you using on Android ? Are you sure it is just a straightforward FFT - it doesn't have built-in windowing or anything like that ?

Comment: @PaulR My data is after using the Hanning Window and after adding a padded of zeros to get the length of 4096. The library in Android is JTransform.  You can see the data here http://pastebin.com/UAYtabEN

Comment: @Sergio: well I just plugged your raw data into Octave (MATLAB clone) and it gives the same results as the vDSP FFT (the first value is 441.09803) - so I think the problem is with your Android implementation.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you for the feedback. But i know in Android it's ok, because i have an swift implementation and gives the same result as Android. Now you will ask why i have in swift working and want this in objective-c? :) It's because i need to optimize the performance and because i don't have enough experience in swift.

Comment: @Sergio: well something doesn't add up - either you are not testing with the same data, or some other test condition is different. I've tested your Objective C code (with my fix above) and also verified independently with the raw data and a MATLAB clone, and both give correct results which agree with each other, and with the data point you supplied for your Objective C code. I think you need to go back and look at your tests more carefully, as the problem is not in the code above.

Comment: Just because your Android and Swift code give the same result does not mean they are giving the correct result.

Comment: Hi @PaulR, i found my problem, and the problem was in the input data, my input data is different. Now i have the input data good and this work fine. Thank you for your help. Regards

Comment: @Sergio: thanks for following up on this - good to know that it actually was the data, not the code. An important lesson learned, no doubt!